# Unable to read emails from SOA UMS driver

Tags: email, ssl, soa

I setup the UMS-email driver in SOA 11.1.1.7 em to read emails from our company email account. I used POP3 and enabled SSL. I also imported the SSL Certificate using openSSL. This is how the keystore looks like when I look at it:

```
Your keystore contains 5 entries

certgenca, Mar 22, 2002, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6:G7:H8:I9:J0:K1:L2:M3:N4:O5:P6
-outlook.companyname.com, Apr 29, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
```

However, when I restarted the SOA server and the admin server, I see the following error in the soa_server1.out log file over and over again. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "outlook.companyname.com", port 443, isSSL false
C: QUIT
<Apr 30, 2015 11:12:39 AM AKDT> <Error> <oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.email> <SDP-26123> <Could not initialize Email Store for user username > 
<Apr 30, 2015 11:12:39 AM AKDT> <Error> <oracle.sdp.messaging.driver.email> <SDP-25700> <An unexpected exception was caught.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:161)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:170)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.Pop3EmailStore.initStore(Pop3EmailStore.java:158)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.Pop3EmailStore.initStore(Pop3EmailStore.java:132)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.EmailResourceAdapter.createEmailStore(EmailResourceAdapter.java:1292)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.getInitializedEmailStore(MailboxPollingWorker.java:104)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.run(MailboxPollingWorker.java:47)
at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:788)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:238)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:496)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:360)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:104)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:214)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:157)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:170)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.Pop3EmailStore.initStore(Pop3EmailStore.java:158)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.Pop3EmailStore.initStore(Pop3EmailStore.java:132)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.EmailResourceAdapter.createEmailStore(EmailResourceAdapter.java:1292)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.getInitializedEmailStore(MailboxPollingWorker.java:104)
at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.run(MailboxPollingWorker.java:47)
at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

>

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, changed POP3 to IMAP, disabled SSL and used port 143 and it is working now. Hope this helps someone someday.